# Reactjs not allowing a function to be passed in onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to log to console.log from the ajax function when the button is clicked. Nothing happens when I click the button.

```
var Search = () => (

  var ajax() {
        console.log('ajax')
   }

return (
  <div className="search-bar form-inline">
    <input className="form-control" type="text" />
    <button className="btn hidden-sm-down" onClick={() => ajax()} >
      <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
  </div> 
)
}
```

Comment: The code as posted is malformed-- dropping it into the [babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBAygpuDGALCBeCAKAlKgfBgsAFBEQSiQgBWIAHlhAN4mkunwD2AdgM7sA2MAHR92Ac3QByKrQmZmEAL5EiYGABcArmE4FCpADwATAJbAI8PiG7cAciAC2MFACJucMEgC0AI3AQAZuxg9p7GnHxhMM448hD6YQAOGmrmltZ2ji6BwZ4cnGpg_M4QagCeCU7OajA0asUA9DF6LPreyWpcqVa2DpXeajqIxoaGMJye3CGG7ADunMVcAMIR8ADWKAz0KHjSdJgKEE2sBtwJIDoW3RmVonzlQ3kQt_fGeRPuSNH69afnRy31NpqDqcf7fEzAPBEOSEBRAA) shows a bunch of errors.

Comment: this kind of question is not deserved to be answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct,

you should have:

```
var Search = () => {

   const ajax = () => {
        console.log('ajax')
   }

return (
  <div className="search-bar form-inline">
    <input className="form-control" type="text" />
    <button className="btn hidden-sm-down" onClick={() => ajax()} >
      <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
  </div> 
)
}
```

or

```js
var Search = () => {

   function ajax() {
        console.log('ajax')
   }

return (
  <div className="search-bar form-inline">
    <input className="form-control" type="text" />
    <button className="btn hidden-sm-down" onClick={() => ajax()} >
      <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
  </div> 
)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Search/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

Comment: Yeah, to clarify. Your functions opening bracket is actually a parenthesis as well as your function instantiation is missing instantiation syntax